# Find a number within a list of paths

Tags: python, pathlib

I am trying to create a file into the right directory based on a 4 digit int.
Example: I'm creating an excel file and I want it to be placed into a folder that contains 1234 somewhere in the name like "Folder(1234)_do.
I have the parent directory but it contains a large amount of subdirectories.

I imagine that I could use pathlib and regex maybe but can't really get it to work.

My code:

```
root_dir = '/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/'
path_list = []
for path in Path(root_dir).iterdir():
    if path.is_dir():
         path_list.append(path)
print(path_list)

i = str(2244)
result = any(i in string for string in str(path_list))

print(result)
```

I don't really know how I can search path objects and I'm not really sure where to start to solve this.

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: What us the problem?

Comment: You can use os.walk from os module which can help you to navigate subdirectories also

Comment: You want to find whether a directory name ends with a number?

Comment: @Sujay, I have a number and I know there is a sub directory that has the corresponding number somewhere in the name and I need to find the path for it. So, not ends but contain the number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for, maybe someone else could gain as well.

```
import glob

i = 1234

path_found = glob.glob('/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/*{i}*'.format(i=i))
```

Answer (score 1):

The below should work and return folders that contains '2244'

```
from pathlib import Path

root_dir = '/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/'
i = str(2244)
path_list = [path for path in Path(root_dir).iterdir() if path.is_dir() and i in path]
print(path_list)
```

Comment: Thanks @balderman! Though, when I run your code I get: "TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable" same as I did with mine

Comment: Maybe I could use glob instead?